# Insert HTML Content from URL into HTML (form, div, iframe, ...)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to display the result of this URL

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlin,de&mode=html&appid=...[1](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Berlin,de&mode=html&appid=...)

which looks like

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWRoD.png
```

how can I insert the HTML content from the URL directly into an iframe or div?
Thanks!

Comment: Will the content be an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already are able to get that response html, all you need to do is insert it onto the page

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "<p>some html</p>"
```

Comment: No, I have the link or API URL and I want to get the content in form of html back..

Comment: Why are you not just their embedded widgets?
https://openweathermap.org/widgets-constructor

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be achieved by PHP.

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("ENTER URL HERE");
?>
```

You could do this via JavaScript, but that would require making an AJAX request to get the HTML and then inserting it into the DOM. I don't think that this would be the best method as the page would have already loaded without the code and then asynchronously adding it to the page. Depending on how it is meant to be viewed, I think this would lead to a poorer UX.

**Edit**

To download the HTML asynchronously, you should use .get(), instead of .load().

```
$.get("URL", function(data) {
    $(".mydiv").html(data);
});
```

Comment: I have two text bars, one of the city and one for the country. The values are passed in the link. I would like, that if I hit a button, the weather status for a city is displayed, like in the screenshot. Can you give me a help please, how I could realize it with JavaScript? I tried it with the JQuery .load method but it doesn't work..